# Does Opera extension manifest have a similar set default tab page like Chrome?

Tags: opera-extension

I'm trying to port a Chrome extension to Opera.

In my chrome manifest.json I have the following lines which tells the Chrome browser to use a specific html page when it launches and whenever it opens a new tab.

```
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "my-page.html"
},
```

How would one create this same action in Opera? I looked at the Browser and Page actions but they don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not supported in Opera.

Comment: Not quite the answer I want to hear but I appreciate the response.